# Blank Screen/Command prompt on Ubuntu/Window 8.1 daul boot toshiba laptop

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

For the last few days I have been trying to configure a laptop to dual boot. The laptop works works very well booting into both ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Widows 81. without any issue until I install item 1 (I need these updates for Android Development work). The same issue can be duplicated by installing item 2. The blank screen / command line appears after the GRUB menu.

1. ```
   sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential zip curl libc6-dev libncurses5-dev:i386 x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev:i386 libreadline6-dev:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib mingw32 openjdk-6-jdk tofrodos python-markdown libxml2-utils xsltproc zlib1g-dev:i386 minicom tftpd uboot-mkimage expect libgl1-mesa-dri

   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so
   ```
2. ```
   sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
   ```

   Per the follwing post ["how do I install intel graphic drivers"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166224/how-do-i-install-the-intel-graphics-driver-in-my-system?answertab=oldest#tab-top) It is my understanding that the Intel Graphic drivers are part of the xserver-xorg-video-intel driver package.

Note: I have reviewed other posts but doesn't seem to find a solution. Thus this post.

**Main Hardware**

1. Toshiba Satellite C55-A5310
2. Intel i3-3120M processor
3. Intel® HD Graphics 4000 (Ivy Bridge GPU)

**Software**

1. Window 8.1
2. Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (uname -r > 3.8.0-35-generic)

Summary of what I have tried so far:

1. change quiet Splash to nomodeset.
2. sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
3. edit grub -> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset", GRUB_GFXMODE=1366x768, update-grub -> stuck at ubuntu splash, (starting CUPS printing spooler/server OK)

**References**

1. [Dual-boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10 in UEFI mode](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2013/03/12/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-04-in-uefi-mode/)
2. [Installing ubuntu along side windows 8](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I was able to resolve the issue. Following is the summary

- Issue #1 I believe  `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel` was installing incorrect drivers for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. (Expert opinion is sorted)

**Solution:** `Sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-precise`

- Issue #2 The following errors we observed.

  "Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/Release"

Based on the following [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1983220) poor internet connection might have contributed to the issue. Thus went to local library to mitigate the issue.

- Issue #3 There might have been some package management issues, suggest by this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157840/why-does-apt-get-fail-to-resolve-the-mirror).

Made the following changes to `sources.list` file to mitigate issues #3.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

The following line were added at beginning of the file

```
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

All in all the Windows 8.1/Ubuntu 12.04 LTS stared to work as expected.

Thank you community for sharing suggestions. Hopefully someone else can benifit from these notes.