# Black screen booting Ubuntu and from LiveUSB

Tags: boot, uefi

I recently dual booted my Windows 8 with Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit on EFI.

I followed the standard procedure and did `boot-repair` in the end.

Now, when I choose Ubuntu option from the grub menu, all I get is a black screen. Also ,if I now try to reinsert my Pen Drive (UEFI), and try to boot from it, I get a black screen again. What can the possible issue be?

Comment: I had similar problems when I configured Ubuntu 12.04 LTS / Window 8.1. I have posted the issues and solutions [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/402242/blank-screen-command-prompt-on-ubuntu-window-8-1-daul-boot-toshiba-laptop). Hope these suggestion will help you. Good luck

Comment: Well this would help if I could open the Ubuntu gui/terminal which I am unable to

Comment: You sure you can boot from the pendrive?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to tweak your kernel boot parameters. One of these three should enable the system to bypass some hangups that are happening and let you boot.

`noacpi` `acpi_osi=linux` `nomodeset`

To change boot parameters:

1. As the machine is booting up, hold **SHIFT** until you get to the GNU Grub menu.
2. Select the most recent Ubuntu kernel and press **`e`** to edit options.
3. Find the line starting with 'linux' and scroll to the end of it after 'quiet splash'
4. Press space and enter `noacpi` and/or `acpi_osi=linux` at the end of the line.

   - If neither works go with `nomodeset`

If you run into any problems these links should help. They contain more detailed info about:

- [Changing Kernel Boot Parameters](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters)
- [Ubuntu's Boot Options](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions)
- [Giant list of Linux Kernel Parameters](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt)

Comment: Didn't work. :(

Comment: @Ranveer What didn't work? Did you try all three options? What happened? Any changes?

Comment: @Ranveer Also you might want to try checking out [SuperGrubDisk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/) if none of the boot options are helping.