# The ubuntu stuck on boot screen, terminal works but GUI doesn't

Tags: boot

I just performed a clean installation on my Computer, and it stuck on the loading screen at first startup. However, the terminal still works. I have tried update the graphic drivers (nvidia gtx 760), but it did not work. What should I do?

Comment: Hello.
Try logging into your Terminal and using `startx` and `sudo lightdm restart`. If that doesn't work, use `sudo apt-get install gdm` and say `<Yes>` when it asks you to.
(I am recommending installing gdm because when I ran Saucy, LightDM often failed on me and I've found gdm to be MUCH more stable)

Comment: Try running this command in the terminal: "grep EE /var/log/Xorg.0.log" and post the output here. It will display any error information in the log file of the X server.

Comment: I have tried all above, but none of them work. Tried to update the lethal, sort and drivers. The screen crashes and blinks after splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS base on the tag. I had a similar issue. Try executing the following.

```
Sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-precise
```

I also have documented few more tips [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402242/blank-screen-command-prompt-on-ubuntu-window-8-1-daul-boot-toshiba-laptop/402544#402544).

Comment: Still did not work, the command line is working fine but the GUI crashed

Comment: @UbuntuNew, Read this post, hopefully you will find something useful http://askubuntu.com/questions/402242/blank-screen-command-prompt-on-ubuntu-window-8-1-daul-boot-toshiba-laptop/402544#402544

Comment: @UbuntuNew: Also look at this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it (Author Luis Alvarado), there is some references to Nvidia graphic drivers. –  Mahendra Gunawardena

Comment: @UbuntuNew: Also check out this post. http://askubuntu.com/questions/403546/cant-add-nvidia-apt-get-repository You might find information that might be helpful.

Comment: What I have tried is to update whatever the apt-get carries, perform a clean installation of the nvidia drive, all did not work. Well, it works in someway. When I checked the additional drivers, it appears the nvidia driver 319 was activated but not working that time. it seems to be a hardware issue..... I may try to instal a 13.10, and see what happens