# Can't add NVIDIA apt-get repository

Tags: nvidia, apt

I can't add the needed repository to install `nvidia-graphics-drivers-319`. I don't understand why the key is not trusted. See the output of the needed commands:

```
root@barry-III:/home/zombie# add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
 Updated versions of X.org drivers, libraries, etc. for Ubuntu.

This PPA is for stable upstream releases of X.org components.  If you're looking for something even more bleeding-edge, please see the xorg-edgers PPA.

While Ubuntu does not "officially/formally" support these packages, if you discover problems when installing these debs please feel free to report bugs to launchpad.  However, please make sure to clearly state that you are running packages from this PPA so we know the fixes need to come here.

If you are upgrading from one release to another with this PPA activated, please install the ppa-purge package and use it to downgrade everything in here beforehand. sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates will do it.

[Directions for packaging drivers can be seen at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/DriverBuilding]
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmph015_y/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmph015_y/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key AF1CDFA9 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmph015_y/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key AF1CDFA9: public key "Launchpad PPA for Ubuntu-X" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
root@barry-III:/home/zombie# apt-get install nvidia-graphics-drivers-319
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nvidia-graphics-drivers-319
root@barry-III:/home/zombie#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not `nvidia-graphics-drivers-319`,it was `nvidia-319`.So run the below command,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-319
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it installs. I googled for it but only found this page: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/ubuntu-x-swat/precise/main/base/nvidia-graphics-drivers-319 Why doesn't it say that it belongs to the nvidia-319 package?

Comment: search all the packages which was related to nvidia by running `apt-cache search nvidia` command.

Answer (score 1):

After adding the PPA run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To reload the packages list and try again. Make sure the PPA contains packages for the ubuntu release you are currently using.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I only forgot to add it to the listing.