# Unable to install software

Tags: installation, package-management

I'm unable to install packages using `apt-get install` command. It produces an error which says: `E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing`.

After updating it is still unable to install the software. I tried it on both 32 and 64 bit ubuntu. I also could not install it thru the Ubuntu Software Center [Failed to download package files, check your internet connection] - I can access the internet.

The things that i'm trying to install are: mysql-server and libssl-dev. I am clueless as to how to go on. Any help with troubleshooting would be much appreciated. Thanks !

p.s: i have tried as root and with sudo

Screenshots: [installation thru ubuntu software center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIPCB.png), [installation using apt-get install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWgIE.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is similar to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error)
Tell us if you could solve it with the same answer.

Comment: This is weird. I am able to apt-get now. I am guessing its not my machine's fault?
By the way thanks for looking into this! :)