# Can not install openssh server

Tags: openssh

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

I got this error:

```
Err mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt/ precise-updates/main openssh-server i386 1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1.4
  No mirror file '/var/lib/apt/mirrors/mirrors.ubuntu.com_mirrors.txt' found  [Mirror: ]
Err mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt/ precise/main ssh-import-id all 2.10-0ubuntu1
  No mirror file '/var/lib/apt/mirrors/mirrors.ubuntu.com_mirrors.txt' found  [Mirror: ]
Failed to fetch mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt/pool/main/o/openssh/openssh-server_5.9p1-5ubuntu1.4_i386.deb  No mirror file '/var/lib/apt/mirrors/mirrors.ubuntu.com_mirrors.txt' found  [Mirror: ]
Failed to fetch mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt/pool/main/s/ssh-import-id/ssh-import-id_2.10-0ubuntu1_all.deb  No mirror file '/var/lib/apt/mirrors/mirrors.ubuntu.com_mirrors.txt' found  [Mirror: ]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` content is:

```
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise main restricted universe
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Why and how to fix it ?

Comment: can you post the contents of the file /etc/apt/sources.list ?

Comment: Follow this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/91595/224082

Comment: `deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise main restricted universe
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-security main restricted universe multiverse`

Comment: If you type in your browser http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt do you see the list of mirrors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue might be related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-cacher-ng/+bug/1020995. I have tried to use the mirror feature on Ubuntu 14.04 also and gave some errors.

You can backup your /etc/apt/sources.list file

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.orig
```

and create a new one with following content. Replace the **ro.archive.ubuntu.com** with initials from your country (e.g fr, de, us etc).

```
#############################################################
################### OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS ###################
#############################################################

###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

###### Ubuntu Extras Repo
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```