# Unable to update in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: apt, updates, software-center, update-manager, 15.10

I'm unable to run sudo apt-get update successfully for the past few days now.

When running `sudo apt-get update` from terminal, it shows error as,

```
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386cddcd/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386cddcd/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-security/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386cddcd/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'partner/binary-i386cddcd/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/wily/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'partner/binary-i386cddcd/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And when using the Software Updater GUI to update, showing message as,

```
Failed to download repository information
Check your Internet connection
```

[image: Screenshot of update error]

Seems like some entry/configuration got corrupted. I tried changing the channels in the

> Software & Updates

by enabling/disabling the restricted,multiverse options in **Ubuntu Software** tab as well as Canonical Partners option in **Other Software** tab.

[image]

Is there any way to reset/cleanup this repository sources list?

I could've done a re-install of Ubuntu but I'm lazy to reinstall and reconfigure all my softwares and stuff. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your internet connection is working?

Comment: @QkiZ yes i have an active internet connection.

Comment: Thanks all for the help and suggestions. I'm unable to do any 'apt-get update' for more than a month now, so I've removed ubuntu and started using windows again. I'll try for a fresh install later. Thanks again.

Comment: Did you try ping `in.archive.ubuntu.com` or browse `http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/` in internet browser?

Comment: @QkiZ I posted this question from a browser only. How come internet works in browser and not in terminal? And btw, I could see the the 'apt-get update' command working properly, and it fails in the halfway.

Comment: But ping is working to this server?

Comment: Note that 15.10 reaches its End of Life in July 2016 (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) so you will want to upgrade to the latest release

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo -E apt-get update`.

For some reason this is required.

Also the software center will not work cause I don't know how to open the software centre with `sudo -E` enabled...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Anyways, I've removed ubuntu now for a fresh installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on terminal to remove all

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/updates
sudo rm *
```

And then run the below command to get newer ones,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: It didn't worked. Still showing same error.

Comment: Okay this may help

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

if it works:

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base > /dev/null
```

Got it from [apt-get update fails to fetch files, “Temporary failure resolving …” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error).

Comment: Sorry. both didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
[arch=amd64]
```

after deb , but before the URL in `/etc/apt/sources.list`