# Error when updating virtualbox

Tags: apt, virtualbox

I have uninstalled a previous version of virtualbox using `sudo apt-get remove virtualbox` and tried to install the latest version using the information from [this](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) page.

I did

```
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

and

```
sudo apt-get update
```

my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file contains:

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib
```

and the error I get after update is:

```
Err http://download.virtualbox.org trusty InRelease                            

Err http://download.virtualbox.org trusty Release.gpg      
  Unable to connect to download.virtualbox.org:http: [IP: 62.253.3.177 80]
Fetched 4,124 kB in 4min 0s (17.2 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to download.virtualbox.org:http: [IP: 62.253.3.177 80]

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have a problem with your DNS as download.virtualbox.org resolves to the addresses 23.63.99.67 or 23.63.99.89

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/91595/320386) gives a lot of good advice on fixing your issue.

For a quick fix you could add the line:

```
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.254 8.8.8.8
```

To the main network interface in your `/etc/network/interfaces` file, after you've edited it, do changing eth0 to the correct interface name if necessary:

```
ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0
```

Once you've done this check that the name resolves to the correct addresses by using:

```
host download.virtualbox.org
```

If you see 23.63.99.67 and 23.63.99.89 then your update command should work properly.

Comment: My `/etc/network/interfaces` file contains `auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.254 8.8.8.8` after editing it. Is this correct?

Comment: I get `download.virtualbox.org is an alias for download.oracle.com.edgesuite.net.
download.oracle.com.edgesuite.net is an alias for a1961.d.akamai.net.
a1961.d.akamai.net has address 62.253.3.178
a1961.d.akamai.net has address 62.253.3.177` after running `host download.virtualbox.org`. Is this correct.

Comment: I tried adding the DNS using the GUI and also tried `apt-get update` again with the same error. I live in the UK. :)

Comment: I did a reverse DNS lookup using `host 62.253.3.178` and get `178.3.253.62.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer 178.3-253-62.static.virginmediabusiness.co.uk.`.

Comment: Also `host  download.virtualbox.org` shows `download.virtualbox.org is an alias for download.oracle.com.edgesuite.net.
download.oracle.com.edgesuite.net is an alias for a1961.d.akamai.net.
a1961.d.akamai.net has address 62.253.3.177
a1961.d.akamai.net has address 62.253.3.178`

Comment: Yes I'm with Virgin. I have been in contact with virgin regarding low bandwidths I have been experiencing and problems with some streaming services. Strange is that youtube would work on my smart TV but not Netflix etc. They put me on another channel late last night, when I tried the update again, it seems to have worked. Sorry didn't post a reply then. Very strange I admit. Don't know how I should make this solved but for now it seems to work.