# Error : Running add-apt repository ppa:

Tags: apt, 16.04, ppa

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm running this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
```

and I'm getting this error:

[image]

I've even tried reinstalling `ca-certificates`, but after that the same error occurs.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

Comment: Did you verify your internet connection and DNS resolution?

Comment: Please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images (see [How do I save terminal output to a file?](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apt-get update fails to fetch files, “Temporary failure resolving …” error](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error) – It's about `apt-get` instead of `add-apt-repository` but the underlying issue and its solution(s) are the same.

Answer (score -2):

I was able to add it using the command above. The error message indicates that the host where the repository is stored is not resolvable by your DNS server. But I think that's probably a red-herring. Deleting the ca-certificates and then reinstalling them should work;

```
rm -rf /usr/share/ca-certificates

apt-get --reinstall install ca-certificates
```

Comment: I  tried it but not working.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure. Here's a dumb question, but after you added the repository you did an apt-get update? If you want a workaround you can install the .deb file with the instructions here: https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/android-studio/releases