# sudo add-apt-repository ppa:<some-package> problem!

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, repository, software-sources

**I have UBUNTU 16.04.05 LTS X64** and when I try to add any repositories I'm having the following error!

for example I have used: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps` and the result is:

```
    This PPA Contains Applications for Ubuntu/Linux Mint from different sources but debianized by http://www.NoobsLab.com
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/apps
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 168, in <module>
    if not sp.add_source_from_shortcut(shortcut, options.enable_source):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 768, in add_source_from_shortcut
    self.set_modified_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 492, in set_modified_sourceslist
    self.save_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 658, in save_sourceslist
    self.sourceslist.save()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 413, in save
    files[source.file] = open(source.file, "w")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/noobslab-ubuntu-apps-xenial.list'
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmph_0b92bg/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmph_0b92bg/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key F59EAE4D from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmph_0b92bg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key F59EAE4D: public key "Launchpad PPA for NoobsLab" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
gpg: keyblock resource `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/noobslab_ubuntu_apps.gpg': file open error
gpg: no writable keyring found: eof
gpg: error reading `/tmp/tmph_0b92bg/pubring.gpg': general error
gpg: import from `/tmp/tmph_0b92bg/pubring.gpg' failed: general error
```

it always gives me this error with any sort of repositories that I try to add.
I have tried many solutions I'm going to list them below:

[Error : Running add-apt repository ppa:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771459/error-running-add-apt-repository-ppa)

[How to install certificates for command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645818/how-to-install-certificates-for-command-line/859887)

[Permission denied: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-earth.list'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031553/permission-denied-etc-apt-sources-list-d-google-earth-list)

and many many other solutions given to related problems.
***no one worked for me***.

**is there any solutions here?**

regards

#

output of `file /etc/apt/sources.list` is shown below:

`/etc/apt/sources.list: ASCII text`

Comment: Please, edit your question to post the output of `file /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution on my own.

In `/etc/apt` just create the following directories:

**apt.conf.d**, **preferences.d**, **sources.list.d**, **trusted.gpg.d**
or `sudo mkdir apt.conf.d sources.list.d trusted.gpg.d`

It will do the job.

Regards