# Updated Ubuntu to 16.04 and now have text screen on boot

Tags: boot, nvidia

I updated Ubuntu to 16.04 earlier this week and now I can't even get into the system as I get this text screen on boot.

[image]

I've gone through a number of solutions on here, as it appears to be an issue with my Nvidia driver, but I still can't get it to work.

I went and changed the grub file to nomodeset and read I should be able to get an option to select my driver on boot, but I don't get anything. This screen of writing is what comes up first before I get the text screen.

[image]

When I go into the command prompt to try install or update anything I keep getting these kind of errors.

[image]

Comment: I don't know why those pictures aren't showing up!

Comment: The links are there, that's fine. It appears that you have a problem with DNS. It says there is a temporary failure resolving 5 different addresses over 2 domains (ubuntu.com and google.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this command

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

To fix packages problem. then update

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

If it didn't work check this: 
[Answer on: How do I continue configuration if apt-get was interrupted?](https://askubuntu.com/a/91595/426201)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. I tried the above and it still didn't work. But I managed to get it up and running by simply running the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Why wouldn't this of been installed automatically during the update?