# Resume interupted upgrade (14.04 to 16.04) and

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, updates

My computer crashed while I was upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.

In order to resume the upgrade, I followed the steps in the tutorial [Rescuing an Interrupted Ubuntu Upgrade](https://administratosphere.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/rescuing-an-interrupted-ubuntu-upgrade/), which seems quite useful.

Everything worked fine when I ran the command:

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

But when I ran the command

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

, I get the following error message (I could only take a picture of it as in that computer only the terminal is working)

[image: screenshot of "Temporary failure resolving" errors from APT]

Basically it is saying that it failed to resolve a few packages (e.g. temporary failure to resolve 'gb.archive.ubuntu.com')

I have then found something at [apt-get update fails to fetch files, “Temporary failure resolving …” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error), which I believe is pretty much what I have been experiencing (failure DURING dist upgrade).

However, I noticed that ALL the entries from my `sources.list`
have the name "xenial" after it, therefore I'm afraid closing all the entries from my `source.list` is not the best option. A picture of my sources.list file can be found below:

[image: screenshot showing contents of sources.list in a terminal-based text editor]

Or do anyone of you believe it can be a temporary DNS issue? Or any other thoughts (I have a feeling it has something to do with my sources.list)?

Comment: Avoid interrupting major distribution upgrades while installing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-get update fails to fetch files, “Temporary failure resolving …” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error)

Answer (score 1):

The `sources.list` seems fine and its most likely an issue with the DNS.

You can add `8.8.8.8` as your temporary DNS and see if it helps by running the following command

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null
```

Then run the following

```
sudo apt-get -f install 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If this fixes your temporary resolving messages then either wait and see if your ISP fixes the issue for you or you can permanently add a DNS server to your system:

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base > /dev/null
```

`8.8.8.8` is Google's own DNS server.

Comment: I restarted the computer and it was working (graphical interface was now working and Ubuntu 16.04 was installed). I finished a few updates from the software manager and it seems everything OK.