# Temporary failure resolving ca.archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: apt, package-management, upstart, systemd, recovery-mode

I am trying to run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-standard systemd-sysv` but I keep getting the error: "temporary failure resolving 'ca.archive.ubuntu.com'". I tried following the steps listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/91595/574988) but nothing has worked. Is there a way fix this or at least to download these packages without access to the gui? 
I tried to revert to upstart but that caused boot errors, so now I'm just trying to return to systemd from recovery mode so I can boot up and live my life.

I apologize for any formatting issues, I'm typing this from my phone

Answer (score 5):

Were you in recovery mode after booting from the CD?
In this situation you need to try to add a nameserver like Google's 8.8.8.8 to /etc/resolv.conf. However, it is slightly more difficult in Ubuntu to do this as it uses the resolvconf system.
You can get around that *temporarily* by:

```
rm /etc/resolv.conf
touch /etc/resolv.conf
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
```

before exiting rescue mode, reverse this change

```
rm /etc/resolv.conf
ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: This doesn't add anything to this old question.  The OP also doesn't state if they're on the CD or in rescue mode, so unless they are, this doesn't answer the question either.

Comment: "now I am just trying to return to systemd from recovery mode so I can boot up and live my life". Sounds like what I am describing, and since I just had the identical issue that he describes, and doing what I have said, helped very much solve my problem, I thought I'd add it. So unless I've completely misunderstood, how doesn't it add anything?

Answer (score 0):

"temporary failure resolving" usually is caused by network connectivity issues.
Here for me http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ is reachable.
Is you Ubuntu computer having no Internet access right now ?
If you want just that package, see here :

```
http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=systemd-sysv
```

For example, if you want to download the amd64 version for Xenial,
see here :

```
http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/systemd-sysv/download
```

Similar for http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ubuntu-standard

Comment: Is there a way to test my connection from the terminal? I don't have access to the gui since I'm in recovery mode

Comment: @MattG have you enabled networking? it's normally disabled in recovery mode

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you using ? If you have a network cable attached, try : dhclient