# Aptitude Uninstalled All My Packages

Tags: apt, package-management, aptitude

When I was using apititude to install something (I used aptitude because it installs all dependencies which was helpful) it decided to uninstall ALL my packages which happened to include my graphics drivers and other key programs installed. Now I am stuck trying to get back into my pc using

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

this has come back with the error:

```
"ERR1: http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InReleas
Temporary failure resovling 'gb.archive.ubuntu.com'
```

Comment: Aptitude did not ... you did ;-)  regarding the error see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error for tips and fixes.

Comment: I have been looking at this article and have been trying fixes... None have worked. @Rinzwind

Comment: @Kilian the `@username` should be written at the start of the comment for the other user to be notified. Regarding your problem why would you even try to do a reinstall of an entire like that after you removed it? Just use a usb or a cd. After all you're reinstalling everything, what difference would it make? Do a clean install

Comment: I am sorry you had this happen. Aptitude is no better or worse than any other and Ubuntu is migrating to apt. Usually this sort of thing happens when you either force something or use 3rd party repos. Please post your repos and try another mirror.

Comment: @Lynob oops didn't realise. I cannot find a usb at the moment and it is really annoying as I have important reports to be typing that need to be ready.

Comment: Try another mirror and `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`. If you get errors post your repos and error message. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

Comment: If you do not have networking reinstall WITHOUT FORMATTING that will preserve your data in home

Comment: I have tried downloading it with mirrors. Same error. My sources are as follows:

Comment: deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main 
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main

Comment: Can you post `ifconfig` and can you ping 8.8.8.8 ?

Comment: en3ps0         link encap: Ethernet HWaddr: d9:97:ba:83:XX:XX
                     UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
                     RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0

Comment: `sudo nano /etc/resolveconf` add a line `nameserver 8.8.8.8` save and re try installing ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Its a directory not a file. (/etc/resolveconf)
wait oops I did resolveconf not resolvconf

Comment: Have tried installing again and same error.

Comment: If networking is broken you will need to reinstall

Comment: How? (I'm extremely sorry. I am a noob with linux and ubuntu)

Comment: @Panther I would like to say thank you! I figured it out by using: 
sudo dhclient en3ps0

Comment: Great. If you get you desktop back post the answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-get update fails to fetch files, “Temporary failure resolving …” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the lengthy comments, the OP was able to resolve the problem by running :

```
sudo dhclient en3ps0
sudo install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: I know its been a few years, and I just came across this again. Although I am a good bit more educated on Ubuntu now, this answer still helped me when I was a noob.