# Make dns to sustain after reboot

Tags: networking, kubuntu, dns

Due to some unknown error (supposedly after messing with update links), I was getting `Temporary failure resolving 'packages.microsoft.com'` while using internet without proxy (no problem with proxy set up). So I came up with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error) solution, which I don't understand completely but it works like a charm. I am using Kubuntu-plasma.

In the solution of the link, it says:

> If this fixes your temporary resolving messages then either wait for 24 hours to see if your ISP fixes the issue for you (or just contact your ISP) - or you can permanently add a DNS server to your system:
>   `echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base > /dev/null`

to make the setting sustain after restart.

But on doing so, it says the file does not exist: `tee: /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base: No such file or directory`

Do I need to create such file? Asking this before messing up with the system files to be on the safer side this time. I do not understand this very much and have no idea what to do? Would be very grateful if someone can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to first install `resolvconf` to make the settings permanent.
The mentioned file is created by this package.

```
sudo apt install resolvconf
```

fixed the problem.