# VirtualBox: Ubuntu guest can't connect to Internet

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, virtualbox

I have configured the Ubuntu server (guest) with NAT adapter and configured it in **/etc/network/interfaces** like below:

```
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
```

But doesn't connect to internet:

```
ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

The host machine is a Windows7 with the firewall disabled.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: version is 16.04

Comment: Might I ask why you need a static IP in the NAT configuration of VirtualBox to the server?  You might need to check this for Net DNS Proxy to work:  https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=49066

Comment: I have changed to dhcp, but I don't know what I'm doing. I'm good at programming not in networks

Comment: If I do `ping -c5 66.102.9.147` (IP from google) it works. I have problems with DNS. Because I can't do an `apt-get update`. I have been following this https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error

Comment: Within a VM it is different as it is going through the Network Address Translation (NAT) controller.  It generates its own DHCP. 
 Don't put anything in the `/etc/resolv.conf` file.  Remove the lines from `/etc/network/interfaces` that deals with the enp0s3.  Reboot the VM and let it use the DNS from the host OS.  Are you looking to access your server from outside the VM / Host computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to include your DNS entries, manually.  Try adding this line to your configuration.  Note that these DNS servers are Google's, and will not be able to provide DNS for your local LAN, but will provide DNS for accessing sites on the Internet..

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Reference: https://www.swiftstack.com/docs/install/configure_networking.html

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on internet. The idea is to execute next instruction:

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base > /dev/null
```

This replaces the nameserver (DNS) used on the machine by the Google Public DNS service.