# sudo apt-get update failed me repeatedly

Tags: bug-reporting

I keep getting this output when I run `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:3 http://et.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'et.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://et.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'et.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://et.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'et.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://et.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'et.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://et.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'et.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://et.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'et.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How this problem can be fixed?

Comment: Related: [apt-get update fails to fetch files, “Temporary failure resolving …” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error)

Answer (score 0):

Try edit your `sources.list`
and change with

```
deb http://et.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main inRelease
deb http://et.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main inRelease
deb http://et.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main inRelease
deb http://et.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main inRelease
```

and try again

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: the source.list found in my home right not anywhere else?

Comment: where do you place source.list file, sir

Comment: it is found in here    `aaitldap@AAiT-LDAP:~$ pwd /home/aaitldap`

Comment: editing the source list did not change anything  HELPPPPP

Comment: what the output said sir?