# fix ubuntu after inadvertently uninstalling a lot of things (base programs)

Tags: libreoffice

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and I wanted to upgrade my boost from 1.58 to the latest version because one of the programs I was planning to use requires it. One thread suggested that I need to uninstall the older version first before installing a the newer version. So I did using:

```
sudo apt-get remove 'libboost-.*'
```

Little did I know that hitting enter and yes was the stupidest thing to do. I'm not unfamiliar with removing programs so I did not read what is on the terminal (which programs were to be removed) and my fingers were really faster than my eyes. So when I noticed that the programs in my dashboard (e.g. libreoffice) started to disappear I thought I had to stop the run, which I did. However, the damage has been done. Upon restarting my computer, it's been stuck on the ubuntu splash page with the five dots still changing their colors. It's like that for almost 2 hours now. I'm stupid and I badly need help. Oh, my poor data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Switch to a virtual terminal so you can execute commands by pressing <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + F2</kbd>
2. Become root by running `sudo -s`
3. Reinstall the `ubuntu-desktop` package using `apt install ubuntu-desktop --reinstall`
4. If nothing happens and `apt` says it's already installed, remove the package using `apt remove ubuntu-desktop` and run the reinstall command (step 3) again.
5. Once done reboot the system by typing `reboot`

Comment: Hi Mr. Ives, I could not access the virtual terminal by pressing Ctrl + Alt + F2 on the splash screen.

Comment: Try other F1, F2, F3, etc. keys.

Comment: You can also hold Shift while booting and enter into a recovery (root) terminal.

Comment: I went to the advanced options for ubuntu in the boot menu then went to recovery mode. I enabled the network first then drop to root. I encountered temporary resolved issues which was addressed here (https://askubuntu.com/a/91595/918207). Then, I did what you suggested and everything is now okay. Thank you!