# Failure in DNS name resolution

Tags: server

Hello dear ubuntu users,

I have a problem, that i can't resolve.

At the some time my ubuntu server (18.04.3 LTS) stopped to resolve the domain names.
For the main job it is doing - i don't actually need it as i'm using ip addresses instead of host names, but i can't make any updates. I getting this error:

```
sudo apt-get update

Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
```

As well if i try to ping any of the websites i get:

```
ping www.cnn.com
ping: www.cnn.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

As i'm running software, that is often need's to update, i have to go to and edit the file /etc/resolv.conf

There is only one line:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

If i change it to the gateway or isp nameserver, it works. But after reboot this file automaticaly modified again and again I see only one line with 127.0.0.1 all my changes are gone.

How do i deal with it?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-get update fails to fetch files, “Temporary failure resolving …” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error)

Comment: Please post the content of `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`

Comment: Maythux: thank you for the link. It does not answer my question. It is not ISP problem (other computers on the same network works just fine). Tried to comment ipv6 lines in the file  /etc/hosts, but did not helped.
I believe i have "DNS relay" and i should configure it, instead of modify /etc/resolv.conf, but can't find how to set it up.

Comment: StrabaglSS_Krall: This is content of the file:

# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: yes

TY