# Errors in updating a new installation

Tags: package-management, updates

After installing Ubuntu, I tried to run `sudo apt-get update` which failed with these error messages:

```
sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'  
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'  
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'  
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'  
Reading package lists... Done  
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'    
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'    
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'    
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InReleaseTemporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'   
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: You are not connected to the Internet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-get update fails to fetch files, “Temporary failure resolving …” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error)

Answer (score 0):

Your PC failed to connect to repositories required to update. Was your Ethernet network cable attached?  If you use WiFi instead of Ethernet, had you selected a WiFi access point and passworded in successfully?

Then, in the last three lines, you tried to launch the gedit editor, which was not installed, and is not part of the basic installation. Perhaps you could use nano instead, which is part of the distro?

Comment: connected through the network

Comment: Ethernet and WiFi both connect 'through the network'. Which was it?