# Ubuntu Server 18.04(LTS) sudo apt update & upgrade error

Tags: command-line

I'm using Ubuntu Server 18.04.

I'm not able to run command sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade etc.

Error:

```
Err:! http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic İnrelease

Temporary failure resolving 'tr.archive.ubuntu.com'

Err2 : http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates İnrelease

Temporary failure resolving 'tr.archive.ubuntu.com'

Err3 : http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports İnrelease

Temporary failure resolving 'tr.archive.ubuntu.com'

Err4 : http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security İnrelease

Temporary failure resolving 'tr.archive.ubuntu.com'
```

How I do fix it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-get update fails to fetch files, “Temporary failure resolving …” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error)

Comment: I assume you live in Turkey. Turkish ISPs' DNS servers are notoriously bad. Can you change your Ubuntu machine's DNS servers to something like  8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 (Google public DNS servers)?

Comment: Yeah , I live in Turkey. OK.@FedonKadifeli I'll try it.

Comment: @Melebius OK.I'll try it and I back your feedback. Thx.