# ubuntu installaton

Tags: apt, proxy

I have been following the directions here 
https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi

But, when i get to the final step "sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop"

For each of hundreds of files it says "Failed to fetch [filename]
and finishes with 'Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run "apt-get update"'

So i run apt-get update and that too generates a bunch of errors like this
Err 4: "Temporary failure resolving ports.ubuntu.com"

The tutorial seems quite confident those steps should work.  I'm reading about proxy issues when i google the error messages. i don't have a proxy, seems more likely that the wifi is not working.

Any suggestions or should i just try a different flavor of linux?

I'm using a raspberry pi4 model b
The Ubuntu image is
ubuntu-19.10.1-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-get update fails to fetch files, “Temporary failure resolving …” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error)

Comment: Have you connected an ethernet cable?  (a simpler fix to connecting to internet if you're not familiar with commands to connect to wifi)  Have you connected to wifi?  Can you ping your router?

Answer (score -1):

This was resolved when i plugged into an ethernet cable.

The pi's wifi connection worked fine once installation was complete but not for the setup.