# Lenovo V15-IIL, I can not active the wifi after install Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, lenovo

It's my first question in this amazing hub, net, so a lot of thinks are realy new for me.
I install Ubuntu 20.04 in my computer Lenovo V15-IIL, all the thinks work pretty good, but, I can not active the wifi connection and, the computer hasn't have ethernet.

I was reading a lot of diferent questions, related on that topic. One of the main solutions was install this driver: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88

But when I try to install de "requiremens":
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install make gcc linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential git

The computer can not fix them. "Fallo temporal al resolver ..." & "No se han podido descargar algunos archivos del índice, se han omitido, o se han utilizado unos antiguos en su lugar"

So, I can not finish the installation process. Can someone help me on fix it? ( :

Comment: First, the driver *rtw88* and *rtwpci* are included in Ubuntu 20.04. Second, without any internet connection, you will be unable to easily download and install the dependencies. Finally, let's confirm your exact device. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-get update fails to fetch files, “Temporary failure resolving …” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error)

Answer (score 1):

Connect your laptop to internet by using a LAN cable or USB tethering,
then run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```