# error in installing g++ in ubuntu

Tags: g++

i've been traying to install g++ in my VMware ubuntu but i couldn't, i tried two different commands but still it's saying that there is an error, could you please help me with it.

when i type `sudo apt install g++` instruction this error shows up to me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu g++-9 gcc gcc-9 libasan5
  libatomic1 libbinutils libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dbg libc6-dev libcrypt-dev
  libctf-nobfd0 libctf0 libgcc-9-dev libitm1 liblsan0 libquadmath0
  libstdc++-9-dev libtsan0 libubsan1 linux-libc-dev manpages-dev
Suggested packages:
  binutils-doc g++-multilib g++-9-multilib gcc-9-doc gcc-multilib make
  autoconf automake libtool flex bison gcc-doc gcc-9-multilib gcc-9-locales
  glibc-doc libstdc++-9-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu g++ g++-9 gcc gcc-9
  libasan5 libatomic1 libbinutils libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcrypt-dev
  libctf-nobfd0 libctf0 libgcc-9-dev libitm1 liblsan0 libquadmath0
  libstdc++-9-dev libtsan0 libubsan1 linux-libc-dev manpages-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc6 libc6-dbg
2 upgraded, 24 newly installed, 0 to remove and 127 not upgraded.
Need to get 30.4 MB/38.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 140 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 binutils-common amd64 2.34-6ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libbinutils amd64 2.34-6ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libctf-nobfd0 amd64 2.34-6ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libctf0 amd64 2.34-6ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu amd64 2.34-6ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 binutils amd64 2.34-6ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Ign:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libitm1 amd64 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libatomic1 amd64 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libasan5 amd64 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 liblsan0 amd64 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libtsan0 amd64 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libubsan1 amd64 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libquadmath0 amd64 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libgcc-9-dev amd64 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 gcc-9 amd64 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04
Err:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 gcc amd64 4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libc-dev-bin amd64 2.31-0ubuntu9.1
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Ign:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 5.4.0-52.57
Err:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libcrypt-dev amd64 1:4.4.10-10ubuntu4
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libc6-dev amd64 2.31-0ubuntu9.1
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Ign:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libstdc++-9-dev amd64 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04
Ign:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 g++-9 amd64 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04
Err:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 g++ amd64 4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Ign:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 manpages-dev all 5.05-1
Err:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 manpages-dev all 5.05-1
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libitm1 amd64 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libatomic1 amd64 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libasan5 amd64 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 liblsan0 amd64 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libtsan0 amd64 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libubsan1 amd64 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libquadmath0 amd64 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libgcc-9-dev amd64 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 gcc-9 amd64 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 5.4.0-52.57
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libstdc++-9-dev amd64 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 g++-9 amd64 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/binutils/binutils-common_2.34-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/binutils/libbinutils_2.34-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/binutils/libctf-nobfd0_2.34-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/binutils/libctf0_2.34-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/binutils/binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu_2.34-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/binutils/binutils_2.34-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-10/libitm1_10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-10/libatomic1_10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-9/libasan5_9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-10/liblsan0_10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-10/libtsan0_10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-10/libubsan1_10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-10/libquadmath0_10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-9/libgcc-9-dev_9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-9/gcc-9_9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-defaults/gcc_9.3.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc-dev-bin_2.31-0ubuntu9.1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_5.4.0-52.57_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxcrypt/libcrypt-dev_4.4.10-10ubuntu4_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-dev_2.31-0ubuntu9.1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-9/libstdc++-9-dev_9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-9/g++-9_9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-defaults/g++_9.3.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/manpages/manpages-dev_5.05-1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

and when i try this `sudo apt-get update` instruction this error shows up:

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-get update fails to fetch files, “Temporary failure resolving …” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error)

Comment: actually no do you have a better solution ?