# DNS resolution problem trying to download modules

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dns

I began by trying to `sudo apt-get update` which resulted in

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
```

I attempted this guide [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error/91595#91595) which did not resolve the issue

This is my /etc/resolv.conf file which I made immutable with 'chattr +i' trying to prevent WSL from overwriting it

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 172.24.144.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

For reference, this is my /etc/apt/sources.list file

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
```

I'm out of ideas, guys.

Comment: 172.24.144.1 is a local DNS resolver. Is the DNS service that's running here functional? If not, maybe you should try Google instead (8.8.8.8).

Comment: @ArturMeinild I added Nameserver 8.8.8.8 to the resolv.conf file. Should that not work?

Comment: Try removing the other one (172.24.144.1) so 8.8.8.8 is the primary.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Unfortunately it did not work, I commented out the first one and just left 8.8.8.8.