# Temporary failure when resolving error

Tags: 20.04, package-management, upgrade, updates

I am having trouble downloading a `.deb` package. When I try to get [this file](http://files.tux-users.net/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/kwayland/libkf5waylandserver5_5.68.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb), I get this message:

```
E: Failure to get https://files.tux-users.net/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/kwayland/libkf5waylandserver5_5.68.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb Temporary failure when resolving "files.tux-users.net"
```

How can I solve this problem?

---

Original Message:

**Temporärer Fehlschlag beim Auflösen von »files.tux-users.net«**

> Temporärer Fehlschlag beim Auflösen von »files.tux-users.net«
> E: Fehlschlag beim Holen von https://files.tux-users.net/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/kwayland/libkf5waylandserver5_5.68.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb Temporärer Fehlschlag beim Auflösen von »files.tux-users.net«

Comment: Consider posting in English?

Comment: The file appears to exist. How are you trying to download it? In a browser or via Terminal? Can you [edit] your question to include this detail?

Comment: "*Temporärer Fehlschlag beim Auflösen von »files.tux-users.net«*" is an ordinary network failure, not a strange apt failure. If the mirror does not re-appear, then try a different mirror.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-get update fails to fetch files, “Temporary failure resolving …” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error)