# Temporary failure resolving during apt update on Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: apt, 22.04

My system was running fine before an updater window popped up asking to upgrade. I assumed this was security patches and accepted.  Now docker, anydesk, all systemctl activities won't load and when I run `sudo apt-get update`, I get a lot of errors showing temporary failures in domain resolution. Sorry, I can't copy/paste the text from the KVM console.

[image: screenshot of terminal running apt update, part 1]

[image: screenshot of terminal running apt update, part 2]

Comment: Perusing the logs in /var/log/apt will give some idea of what went down.

Comment: These are DNS resolution errors. This means that for some reason, when you ran this command, your system was not able to get the DNS records for the domains with errors. Sometimes these errors have to do with your DNS server and you can try again later. If the problem continues to occur, check your network settings and see if you can resolve these domains in a web browser.

Comment: Ok, that's helpful.  I notice following my upgrade that my 10Gb SFP+ is no longer up and passing traffic.  The SFP module was removed and I took it up to my office where I verified the cable works.  I am searching to figure out is there something in the upgrade that turned it off, but at a minimum how to turn it back on, as my cloudflare zero tunnel points to it.  I'll try to figure out if I can use redundant ip addresses to prevent this in the future.

Comment: Ok, I kinda figured it out.  Using DAC cable in SFP+ port.  The port was up and working, but following the upgrade it wouldn't recognize it.  I had moved my cloudflare zero tunnel ingress IP's to point to a 1Gb Ethernet copper port, rebooted, which brought everything online. For giggles, I plugged my DAC cable back in and the port/link was recognized and I can ping/pass traffic again.  I've ordered multimode SFP+ & LC/LC fiber to replace it, but I really would like to know two Q's:
1) Does this make sense to anyone?
2) Cloudflared config.yml service point to IP #1 or #2 for redundancy ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-get update fails to fetch files, “Temporary failure resolving …” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error)