# ubuntu 22.04 Error temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: networking, server, bash, dns

I am getting the following error from ubuntu 22.04 terminal, connected via wired ethernet connection: When I type the following command which I am using in a bash script:

```
ping google.com
```

and

```
apt-get update
```

I get the following error:

```
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'archive.
```

Originally, the Internet worked fine, but the above command does not work after apt-get install ntp.

When I installed ntp, I saw system list?? in a purple screen and clicked enter without thinking.

Adding nameserver 8.8.8.8 and nameserver 8.8.4.4 to /etc/resolve.conf does not work either.

A Kubernetes master node is running on that server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!....

please help..

Comment: The answer is in the question it is temporary. What ever DNS you are using is not working at this second. Why it is not working can not be guessed from the info you have given.

Comment: @David What information can I post? 
Please tell me anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-get update fails to fetch files, “Temporary failure resolving …” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error)