# Unable to install openssh server

Tags: ssh, update-manager

I am trying to install OpenSSH server on my Ubuntu 22.04 machine. I executed: `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` and `sudo apt install openssh-server`.

It then exits with the errors:

```
Temporary failure resolving 'gb.archive.ubuntu.com'
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 ncurses-term all 6.3-2ubuntu0.1 Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 ncurses-term all 6.3-2ubuntu0.1 Temporary failure resolving 'gb.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssh/openssh-sftp-server_8.9p1-3ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb esolving 'gb.archive.ubuntu.com
Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssh/openssh-server_8.9p1-3ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ing 'gb.archive.ubuntu.com
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/ncurses/ncurses-term_6.3-2ubuntu0.1_all.deb archive.ubuntu.com"
Temporary failure Temporary failure resol
Temporary failure resolving 'gb.
Temporary failure resolv
E: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/ssh-import-id/ssh-import-id_5.11-0ubuntu1_all.deb ing 'gb.archive.ubuntu.com E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I have tried the action suggested in the error message. I am getting these both as root and as a user with admin privileges. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-get update fails to fetch files, “Temporary failure resolving …” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error) - If you need to paste from your terminal in the future, do not alter the contents of the paste, and please format appropriately so we can parse the information and distinguish it from surrounding text. See: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/20164 for instructions