# cannot install pip, nor update

Tags: python, pip

i have python 3.10.6 installed.
When i install pip Terminal says package python3-pip is not available but is refered to by another package, has no installed candidate (missing, obsolete or only available from another source).
When i update i have temporary failures and fail to fetch problems. The solutions detailed here [apt-get update fails to fetch files, “Temporary failure resolving …” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error/91595#91595)
dont work.
What to do?
Didier

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: thank you, unfortunately not

Comment: but i'll try again, i know nothing about coding so i'm probably at fault