# Unable to access archive/ or security.ubuntu.com

Tags: squid, squid-deb-proxy

Our squid proxy server can no longer access the internet in AWS. When trying to apt-get update:

```
root@ip-172-31-76-59:/home/ubuntu# apt-get update
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
 Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
```

Trying to access cache logs but spits back "permission denied" even as root. May have to do with apparmor installed? Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AppArmor installed prevented access to the DNS settings and unable to validate the settings. It was easy enough to start from scratch and rebuild a new server to resolve this issue.