# How to solve "/dev/nvme0n1p3: clean" error?

Tags: boot, command-line, apt

Once I start my PC I see this line on the top of the screen:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p3: clean
```

Tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then `sudo apt-get update` but it is showing:

```
Failed to fetch http://us.archieve.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'us.archieve.ubuntu.com'
```

How to solve this?

Comment: It doesn't exist. It is http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease. You have a typo there.

Comment: What has the title to do with the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) and [apt-get update fails to fetch files, “Temporary failure resolving …” error](https://askubuntu.com/q/91543)

Comment: Have a look here - might help?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w