Cannot install new programs on system with linux image created with clonezilla
Please help me.
I have created an image with the of a system with Clonezilla and I have restore it on two new systems. Everything was fine until I wanted to install a new program on them from terminal and I get the error:
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-modules-5.15.0-100-generic : Depends: linux-image-5.15.0-100-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                             linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-100-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

I have tried to fix the broken with: apt --fix-broken install, and I get:
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-hwe-5.15/linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-100-generic_5.15.0-100.110~20.04.1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ro.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

For sudo apt-get update and sudo apt update --fix-missing, I get:
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ro.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ro.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ro.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ro.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ro.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ro.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Does anyone know what is the issue?
Internet is working  ok, I tried to ping 8.8.8.8 and it's working
Ubuntu version 20.04.3 LTS

Did you try to fix DNS configuration on the system first?

As the error message suggests Temporary failure resolving 'ro.archive.ubuntu.com' there is either an issue reaching that specific URL or you have a local issue resolving names. Can you ping other domains? I.e. can you access the Internet from that machine from the terminal? If that is the case, you might want to point to a different mirror.

Worked with the solution here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error It seemed there was a DNS issue
