network manager issue and sudo apt update reply ign and temporary failure resolving
enter image description here
enter image description here
Yesterday when uninstall pi-hole it ask me do you wish to remove iproutes2 and git.I thought it was the pi-hole file so i said yes and after that my network manager not working .I try to install iproutes 2 again  but it said package iproute2 has no installation candidate

This question is similar to: What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Providing your message as text (instead of picture of text) allows us to copy/paste details into a browser allowing for more specific detail.  You have access to the text, so you can explore what you added to your system yourself.  I noted numerous errors, I picked & acted on one.

you can see in my picture  I am a new Ubuntu user so I have little experience   Thank all your help

https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error/91585 will possibly be more useful (copying/pasting text into your question is better as easier to read, rather than link pointing to text) is what I'd explore first.  Providing architecture details & full details (eg. release) is also helpful; eg. you mention pi (pi-hole specifically; so raspberry pi??) which uses different URLs to main architecture.

This question is similar to: apt-get update fails to fetch files, “Temporary failure resolving …” error. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
